# Sed command issue in loop

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to read the below file line by line to do the below listed operations

1. extract the directory alone and assign it one variable
2. extract the permission available in the line and add comma between the permissions and assign to another variable
3. Finally apply setfacl logic as shown in the output.

File - bkp.txt

```
# file:  /disk1/script_1/ user::rwx group::r-x group:service:r-x mask::r-x other::r-x
# file:  /disk1/script_1//hello.txt user::rw- group::r-- other::r--
# file:  /disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
```

My Code

```
#!/bin/sh
input="bkp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line;
do
echo $line
file_name=`sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $file_name
file_perm=`sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' "$line" | awk '{$1=""}{print}' | tr ' ' ',' | awk 
'{sub(",","")}1'`
echo $file_perm
echo "setfacl -m "$file_perm" "$file_name" executing"
done <"$input"
```

Required Output

```
setfacl -m user::rwx,group::r-x,group:service:r-x,mask::r-x,other::r-x  /disk1/script_1/
setfacl -m  user::rw-,group::r--,other::r--  /disk1/script_1//hello.txt
setfacl -m  user::rwx,group::r-x,other::r-x   /disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt
```

But ending with the below error

```
sed: can't read # file: /disk1/script_1/ user::rwx group::r-x group:service:r-x mask::r-x 
other::r-x: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` program works on file (on stdin). You can not pass it a string on the command line. Replace lines like:

```
file_name=`sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

With

```
file_name=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' | awk '{print $1}')
```

It looks that the input is space separated. You can also combine the sed and awk into a single `awk'

```
file_name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Or change the read statement (no need to override IFS) to read the file and acl directly.

```
while read x1 x2 file_name file_perm ; do
    echo "setfacl -m '$file_perm' '$file_name' executing"
    setfacl -m "$file_perm" "$file_name"
done < "$input"
```